# How to use one form and action class on multiple pages JSP

Tags: struts-1

How to use same form beans and action class on multiple pages? do i need to create one form bean and action class that exactly have same variable for other JSP pages? thanks in advance.    How to use those form and action class in Dashboard.jsp? i just want to display data of vendor in dashboard.jsp.

below is example code:

**VendorInfoForm.java**

```
package com.pms.reference;

import com.base.utility.DateUtil;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Date;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class VendorInfoForm extends org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm {

    private String vivendorID;
    private String vivendorShortname;
    private String vivendorName;

public String getVivendorID() {
        return vivendorID;
    }

    public void setVivendorID(String vivendorID) {
        this.vivendorID = vivendorID;
    }

    public String getVivendorName() {
        return vivendorName;
    }

    public void setVivendorName(String vivendorName) {
        this.vivendorName = vivendorName;
    }

    public String getVivendorShortname() {
        return vivendorShortname;
    }

    public void setVivendorShortname(String vivendorShortname) {
        this.vivendorShortname = vivendorShortname;
    }
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
        return errors;
    }
}
```

**VendorInfoAction.java**

```
package com.pms.reference;

import com.base.constant.MessageConstant;
import com.base.utility.BaseUtil;
import com.base.utility.DateUtil;
import com.hbs.base.entities.ComAccessLevel;
import com.hbs.base.entities.ComUserProfiles;
import com.hbs.base.entities.ComAccessLevel;
import com.htp.web.base.BaseAction;
import com.htp.web.base.constant.PageConstant;
import com.htp.web.utility.WebUtil;
import com.pms.reference.entities.ASVendorInfo;
import com.pms.reference.entities.HDPersonInfo;
import com.pms.reference.entities.RefState;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

public class VendorInfoAction extends BaseAction {

   private final static String JSP_LIST = "/jspNew/pms/reference/VendorInfoList.jsp";
    private final static String JSP_CREATE = "/jspNew/pms/reference/VendorInfoCreate.jsp";
    private final static String JSP_READ = "/jspNew/pms/reference/VendorInfoRead.jsp";
    private final static String JSP_UPDATE = "/jspNew/pms/reference/VendorInfoUpdate.jsp";

    public ActionForward executeAction(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws  IOException, ServletException {

        VendorInfoForm formBean = (VendorInfoForm)form;

        String action = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "hdAction");
        String nextJSP = "";

        try {
            if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.MENU) ||
                BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.LIST) ||
                BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.GET_SORTING)) {
                nextJSP = getList(request, action);
            }
            else if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.GET_CREATE)) {
                nextJSP = getCreate(request, action);
            }
            else if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.CREATE) ||
                    BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.UPDATE)) {
                nextJSP = doCreateOrUpdate(request, action, formBean);
            }
            else if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.DELETE)) {
                nextJSP = doDelete(request, action);
            }
            else if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.GET_READ)
                    || BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.GET_UPDATE)) {
                nextJSP = getReadOrUpdate(request, action);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return new ActionForward(nextJSP);
    }

    private String getList(HttpServletRequest request, String action) throws Exception{

        ComUserProfiles profile = (ComUserProfiles)request.getSession().getAttribute("PROFILE");
        lookupComAccessLevel();
        ComAccessLevel accessLevel = comAccessLevelFacade.find(profile.getAclId());
        request.setAttribute("accessLevel", accessLevel);

        String input = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "txtSchAll");
        input = BaseUtil.replaceQuickSearch(input);// modified by din 20/05/2015
        String pageNo = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "hdPgNo");
        String sortOrder = "";
        String sortId = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "sortId");

        if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.MENU)) {
            manageCommonSession(request, "Vendor");
        }

        // ----------------- Start Sorting -------------//
        manageSortingSession(request, sortId);
        sortId      = BaseUtil.getStr(request.getSession().getAttribute("sortingId"));
        sortOrder   = BaseUtil.getStr(request.getSession().getAttribute("sortingOrder"));
        // ------------------ End Sorting --------------//

        Integer maxNo = BaseUtil.getInt(request.getSession().getAttribute("DISPLAY"));
        Integer firstNo = ((pageNo!=null && !pageNo.equalsIgnoreCase("")?Integer.parseInt(pageNo):1) - 1) * maxNo;

        lookupASVendorInfo();
        int[] range = new int[]{firstNo, maxNo};
        List<ASVendorInfo> list = aSVendorInfo.findAll(input, range, sortId, sortOrder);
        int totalRecord = aSVendorInfo.findTotal(input);

        request.setAttribute("list", list);
        request.setAttribute("currentpageno", pageNo);
        request.setAttribute("totalrecords", String.valueOf(totalRecord));
        request.setAttribute("noofpages", String.valueOf(totalRecord / range[1] + (totalRecord % range[1] == 0 ? 0 : 1)));
        request.setAttribute("recordstartno", firstNo);
        request.setAttribute("searchinput", input);

        return JSP_LIST;
    }

    private String getCreate(HttpServletRequest request, String action) throws Exception{

        if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.MENU)) {
            manageCommonSession(request, "Vendor");
        }

        lookupHDPersonInfo();
        List<HDPersonInfo> personList = hDPersonInfo.findAllByPersonType("3");
        request.setAttribute("personList", personList);

        lookupRefState();
        List<RefState> stateList = refStateFacade.findAll();
        request.setAttribute("stateList", stateList);

        return JSP_CREATE;
    }

    private String doCreateOrUpdate(HttpServletRequest request, String action, VendorInfoForm src) throws Exception{

        ComUserProfiles profile = (ComUserProfiles)request.getSession().getAttribute("PROFILE");
        String msgInfo = "";
        String msgType = "";

        ASVendorInfo dest = new ASVendorInfo();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dest, src);

        try {
            msgType = MessageConstant.SUCCESS;
            lookupASVendorInfo();
            if(BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.UPDATE)){
                dest.setVivendorShortname(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getVivendorShortname()));
                dest.setViAddress1(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress1()));
                dest.setViAddress2(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress2()));
                dest.setViAddress3(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress3()));
                dest.setViUpdateDate(new Date(DateUtil.getCurrentDateTime()));
                dest.setViUpdateId(profile.getId());
                dest.setViActiveSts(BaseUtil.getStr(src.getViActiveSts()));
                aSVendorInfo.edit(dest);
                msgInfo = MessageConstant.RECORD_UPDATE_SUCCESS + ". <a href=\""+request.getContextPath()+"/VendorInfo.do?hdAction=getRead&id=" + dest.getVivendorID() + "\" data-toggle=\"ajaxModal\" >View Here.</a>";
            }
            else {
                dest.setVivendorID("");
                dest.setVivendorShortname(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getVivendorShortname()));
                dest.setViAddress1(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress1()));
                dest.setViAddress2(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress2()));
                dest.setViAddress3(BaseUtil.getStrUpper(src.getViAddress3()));
                dest.setViCreateDate(new Date(DateUtil.getCurrentDateTime()));
                dest.setViCreateId(profile.getId());
                dest.setViActiveSts(BaseUtil.getStr(src.getViActiveSts()));
                String vendorId = aSVendorInfo.createVendorInfo(dest);
                msgInfo = MessageConstant.RECORD_CREATE_SUCCESS + ". <a href=\""+request.getContextPath()+"/VendorInfo.do?hdAction=getRead&id=" + vendorId + "\" data-toggle=\"ajaxModal\" >View Here.</a>";
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            msgType = MessageConstant.ERROR;
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.UPDATE)) {
                msgInfo = MessageConstant.RECORD_UPDATE_FAILED;
            }
            else {
                msgInfo = MessageConstant.RECORD_CREATE_FAILED;
            }
        }

        request.setAttribute("errMsg", BaseUtil.getMessage(msgType, msgInfo));
        return getList(request, action);
    }

    private String getReadOrUpdate(HttpServletRequest request, String action) throws Exception{

        String id = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "id");

        if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.MENU)) {
            manageCommonSession(request, "Vendor");
        }

        lookupHDPersonInfo();
        List<HDPersonInfo> personList = hDPersonInfo.findAllByPersonType("3");
        request.setAttribute("personList", personList);

        lookupRefState();
        List<RefState> stateList = refStateFacade.findAll();
        request.setAttribute("stateList", stateList);

        lookupASVendorInfo();
        ASVendorInfo o = aSVendorInfo.find(id);
        request.setAttribute("obj", o);

        if (BaseUtil.isEqualsCaseIgnore(action, PageConstant.GET_UPDATE)) {
            return JSP_UPDATE;
        }
        else {
            return JSP_READ;
        }
    }

    private String doDelete(HttpServletRequest request, String action) throws Exception{
        String id = WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "id");

        lookupASVendorInfo();
        ASVendorInfo o = aSVendorInfo.find(id);
        aSVendorInfo.remove(o);

        return getList(request, action);
    }

    @Override
    protected void manageCommonSession(HttpServletRequest request, String formName) throws Exception {
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("sortingOrder");
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("sortingId");
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("formName");
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("menuId");
        request.getSession().removeAttribute("txnId");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("formName", formName);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("menuId", WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "menuId"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("txnId", WebUtil.getStrInput(request, "txnId"));
    }
}
```

**Dashboard.jsp**

```
<%@page import="com.htp.web.base.constant.PageConstant"%>
<%@page import="org.json.JSONObject"%>
<%--@ page language="java" contentType="application/json; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"--%>
<%@page import="com.pms.reference.entities.HDCaseMaster"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.hbs.base.entities.ComUserProfiles"%>
<%@page import="com.base.utility.BaseUtil"%>
<%
    String userID = "";

    HDCaseMaster o = (HDCaseMaster) request.getAttribute("obj");
    if (o == null) {
        o = new HDCaseMaster();
    }

    ComUserProfiles profile = (ComUserProfiles) request.getSession().getAttribute("PROFILE");
    List<HDCaseMaster> masterList = (List) request.getSession().getAttribute("masterList");

    if (profile != null) {
        if (!profile.equals("")) {
            userID = profile.getId();
        }
    }
%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

        <ul class="breadcrumb no-border no-radius b-b b-light pull-in">
            <li><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Dashboard</li>
        </ul>
              <!--<content-page></content-page>-->
            <div class="m-b-md">
              <h3 class="m-b-none">Dashboard</h3>
              <small>Welcome back, <%=BaseUtil.getStr(profile.getNickName())%></small> </div>

                  <%

                   JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("city", "Mumbai");
                    json.put("country", "India");


                  %>
                  <%=json.toString()%>
                  <%=o.getCmStatus()%>

               <section class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="row m-l-none m-r-none bg-light lter">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 padder-v b-r b-light min-box-height"> <span class="fa-stack fa-2x pull-left m-r-sm"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-info"></i> <i class="fa fa-user fa-stack-1x text-white"></i> </span> <a class="clear" href="javascript:getMenuPage('/CaseMaster.do?hdAction=getStartPage&menuId=M0302&txnId=M03T02');"> <span class="h3 block m-t-xs"><strong>Incident</strong></span> <small class="text-muted text-uc">Add New Incident</small> </a> </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 padder-v b-r b-light min-box-height"> <span class="fa-stack fa-2x pull-left m-r-sm"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-info"></i> <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-stack-1x text-white"></i> </span> <a class="clear" href="javascript:getMenuPage('/SLA.do?hdAction=getStartPage&menuId=M0402&txnId=M04T02');"> <span class="h3 block m-t-xs"><strong>SLA</strong></span> <small class="text-muted text-uc">Add New SLA</small> </a> </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 padder-v b-r b-light min-box-height"> <span class="fa-stack fa-2x pull-left m-r-sm"> <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-info"></i> <i class="fa fa-edit fa-stack-1x text-white"></i> </span> <a class="clear" href="javascript:getMenuPage('/GenReport.do?hdAction=getStartPage&menuId=M0502&txnId=M05T02');"> <span class="h3 block m-t-xs"><strong>Report</strong></span> <small class="text-muted text-uc">Incident Report</small> </a> </div>

              </div>
            </section>
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- .crousel slide -->
                <section class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="carousel slide auto panel-body" id="c-slide">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators out">
                      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                      <li data-target="#c-slide" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
                    </ol>
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                      <div class="item active">
                        <p class="text-center"> <em class="h4 text-mute">Save your time</em><br>
                          <small class="text-muted">Many components</small> </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <p class="text-center"> <em class="h4 text-mute">Nice and easy to use</em><br>
                          <small class="text-muted">Full documents</small> </p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="item">
                        <p class="text-center"> <em class="h4 text-mute">Mobile header first</em><br>
                          <small class="text-muted">Mobile/Tablet/Desktop</small> </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#c-slide" data-slide="prev"> <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#c-slide" data-slide="next"> <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> </a> </div>
                </section>
                <!-- / .carousel slide --> </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                <section class="panel panel-default portlet-item">
                  <header class="panel-heading bg-primary"> News </header>
                  <section class="panel-body">
                    <article class="media"> <span class="pull-left thumb-sm"><img src="../../images/avatar_default.jpg" class="img-circle"></span>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="pull-right media-xs text-center text-muted"> <strong class="h4">12:18</strong><br>
                          <small class="label bg-light">pm</small> </div>
                        <a href="#" class="h4">Bootstrap 3 released</a> <small class="block"><a href="#" class="">John Smith</a> <span class="label label-success">Circle</span></small> <small class="block m-t-sm">Sleek, intuitive, and powerful mobile-first front-end framework for faster and easier web development.</small> </div>
                    </article>
                    <div class="line pull-in"></div>
                    <article class="media"> <span class="pull-left thumb-sm"><i class="fa fa-file-o fa-3x icon-muted"></i></span>
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="pull-right media-xs text-center text-muted"> <strong class="h4">17</strong><br>
                          <small class="label bg-light">feb</small> </div>
                        <a href="#" class="h4">Bootstrap documents</a> <small class="block"><a href="#" class="">John Smith</a> <span class="label label-info">Friends</span></small> <small class="block m-t-sm">There are a few easy ways to quickly get started with Bootstrap, each one appealing to a different skill level and use case. Read through to see what suits your particular needs.</small> </div>
                    </article>
                    <div class="line pull-in"></div>
                    <article class="media">
                      <div class="media-body">
                        <div class="pull-right media-xs text-center text-muted"> <strong class="h4">09</strong><br>
                          <small class="label bg-light">jan</small> </div>
                        <a href="#" class="h4 text-success">Mobile first html/css framework</a> <small class="block m-t-sm">Bootstrap, Ratchet</small> </div>
                    </article>
                  </section>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                <section class="panel panel-default">
                  <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Incident Logs Created This Month</header>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row text-sm wrapper">
                      <div class="col-sm-12 m-b-xs text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group m-b" data-toggle="buttons">
                          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default active btn-info">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnMonth">
                            Month </label>
                          <label class="btn btn-sm btn-default btn-info">
                            <input type="radio" name="options" id="btnWeek">
                            Week </label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div id="flot-test" style="height:265px"></div>
                        <!--<div id="namaHari"></div>-->
                    </div>  
                  </div>
                  <footer class="panel-footer bg-white no-padder">
                      <%--<%=masterListDisplay %>--%>
                      <%
                   //  int count [] = new int [5];
                    //  if(masterListDisplay != null){
                      //    for(HDCaseMaster o : masterListDisplay ){
                     //          if(BaseUtil.isEquals(BaseUtil.getStr(o.getCmStatus()), "4")){count[0]=count[0]+1;}
                          //     else if(BaseUtil.isEquals(BaseUtil.getStr(o.getCmStatus()), "5")){count[1]=count[1]+1;}
                          //     else if(BaseUtil.isEquals(BaseUtil.getStr(o.getCmStatus()), "6")){count[2]=count[2]+1;}
                          //    else if(BaseUtil.isEquals(BaseUtil.getStr(o.getCmStatus()), "7")){count[3]=count[3]+1;}
                           //    else
                                 //   count[4]=count[4]+1;                           
                        //    }
                       // }
                      %>


                    <div class="row text-center no-gutter">
                      <div class="col-xs-3 b-r b-light btn-success"> 
                          <span class="h4 font-bold m-t block">

                           </span> <small class="text-white m-b block ">Open Logs<div id="openLog"></div></small> </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-3 b-r b-light btn-warning"> <span class="h4 font-bold m-t block">System.out.print(GetTotalLog())</span> <small class="text-white m-b block ">Resolved Logs</small> </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-3 b-r b-light btn-info"> <span class="h4 font-bold m-t block">System.out.print(GetTotalLog())</span> <small class="text-white m-b block ">Closed Logs</small> </div>
                      <div class="col-xs-3 btn-danger"> <span class="h4 font-bold m-t block">System.out.print(GetTotalLog())</span> <small class="text-white m-b block ">Duplicate/Cancel Logs</small> </div>
                    </div>
                  </footer>
                </section>
                </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"> 
                <section class="panel panel-default">
                  <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Total Incident Logs Created by Month</header>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                   <div id="flot-bar" style="height:150px"></div>
                  </div>
                </section>
                    </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <section class="panel panel-default">
                  <header class="panel-heading font-bold">Data By Day</header>
                  <div class="bg-light dk wrapper"> <span class="pull-right">Wednesday</span> <span class="h4">07-11-2014<br>
                    <small class="text-muted"></small> </span>
                    <div class="text-center m-b-n m-t-sm">
                      <div class="sparkline" data-type="line" data-height="65" data-width="100%" data-line-width="2" data-line-color="#dddddd" data-spot-color="#bbbbbb" data-fill-color="" data-highlight-line-color="#fff" data-spot-radius="3" data-resize="true" values="280,320,220,385,450,320,345,250,250,250,400,380"></div>
                      <br/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="panel-body">
                    <div> <span class="text-muted">Total:</span> <span class="h3 block">53 <small class="text-muted">log(s) created</small></span> </div>
                  </div>
                </section>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <section class="panel b-light">
                  <header class="panel-heading bg-primary no-border"><strong>Calendar</strong></header>
                  <div id="calendar" class="bg-primary-lt m-l-n-xxs m-r-n-xxs"></div>
                  <div class="list-group"> <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-ellipsis"> <span class="badge bg-danger">7:30</span> Meet a friend </a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-ellipsis"> <span class="badge bg-success">9:30</span> Have a kick off meeting with .inc company </a> <a href="#" class="list-group-item text-ellipsis"> <span class="badge bg-light">19:30</span> Milestone release </a> </div>
                </section>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: be more specific please and show some code

Comment: i already added some code above :)